# Socket accept and waitpid in parent

Tags: c, sockets, fork, waitpid

I have a parent that is waiting for a pool and then do a waitpid in a while loop.

```
poll_list[0].fd = server_fd;
poll_list[0].events = POLLIN;
retval = poll(poll_list, 1, 3500);
if (retval == -1)
{
    my_error(stderr,
             "%s: Error setting pool %d", __func__, __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (retval > 0)
{ // There was an accept
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *)&addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        my_error(stderr,
                 "%s: Accepted error of near line %d", __func__, __LINE__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
...
// Forker pour créer un processus enfant
while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
```

However during 3,5s, I may have zombie processes. I can reduce the pool timeout but is there a better solution to manage socket accept and children management?

[image: zombie processes]

Thanks.

With SIGCHLD, I have this :

```
void childsignal()
{
    pid_t status;
    int pid;
    while ((pid=waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG))>0)
    {
        my_error(stderr, "Parent: The child process %d caught signal %d and exited", pid, status);
        if (!WIFEXITED(status)) // process exit abnormally, need to log.
            my_error(stderr, "Parent: The child process %d caught signal %d and exited", pid, status); //Never executed
    };
}
```

For instance, if process `a` exits succesfully, first error would log but if process `b` is killed by a signal, nothing would show.

Comment: If the status of the child does not matter for you set signal SIGCHLD to SIG_IGN. If you want to get the status immediately after the childs exit setup a signal handler for SIGCHLD.

Comment: Actually I have a signal handler and error logging on children so nothing is indeed used afterwards. But those function should trigger before the process turns as zombie... so might seem like a good idea. I'II check. Regarding `If you want to get the status immediately after the childs exit setup a signal handler for SIGCHLD`, would it work if parent is blocked? (by accept for instance).

Comment: *"would it work if parent is blocked?"* - signal handlers have priority. Note that accept (and other system calls) might fail when interrupted by a signal and you need to call it again.

Comment: Okay, I will go for the second option. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a `SIGCHLD` handler, you do _not_ a `waitpid` loop in the main (i.e. the handler does the `waitpid` loop). And, you don't need `poll` at all. Just loop on `accept` (doing a `fork`). You have to catch an error return from `accept` (and loop if `errno == EINTR`).

Comment: I have tried `SIGCHLD` and `accept` loop. But I always get status 0 from process even if some processes are killed by SIGTERM, I could not get them. However the accept loop seems to work with @CraigEstey method.

Comment: I'd replace `WNOHANG` with `0`, so that `waitpid()` doesn't return until the child process has properly exited (and therefore the zombie can be disposed of)

Comment: The zombie is not sure to be prepared when `SIGCHLD` is called? You mean only the first condition right? Because else, it would block forever...